# Scrolled down when landing even with no JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, events, scroll

I'm facing an issue since few days. When users land to our website they are automatically scrolled down at the bottom of the page.
I just can't provide the website I'm really sorry.
There is no anchor in the URI, no such things related to scroll.

When I was reproducing the behaviour I disabled the JavaScript to eliminate this track. Even with no JS the behaviour is the same.

Almost of our users use Firefox as web browser. I figured out that issue is constantly happening on Firefox instead of Chrome which is happening randomly.

Do you have any idea what could cause that behaviour, event when the JS is disabled ?

If anyone has faced this issue and can be helpful to dig with us do not hesitate !

Thanks again

Comment: Anchor target in the uri? With absolutely no context or test case, I don't really see how we can help at all.

Comment: No anchor in the url, a simple and clean url like google.com. I just can't provide the website I'm sorry, and I cannot reproduce it because I don't know how it works.

Comment: Then we can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Check if you have <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=#post-msg"> kind of tags in your page, mainly look for url=# in meta tag

Comment: I took a look and no such things like you're describing is present in our code :/ Thanks appreciated

Comment: @Disfigure> copy the full page to a test server. See if it still does that. If so, delete some content and check again. Repeat. 1) You will probably find the culprit that way and 2) if you don't you will end up with a tiny page that still exhibits the behavior and has no sensitive content, which you'll be able to post here. See also [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No way the issue is out of the page, we deployed on different environment and multiple server, tested on lot of computers so that's in our code I think. That what I'm actually doin haha

Comment: @spectras I'll check your link, appreciated. If I can provide a exemple I'll edit the post

Comment: apprently its coming form the structure of our menu, I dont understand why lol currently searching

Comment: The issue was an input with the "autofocus" attribute with the style property "display: none" which caused the scroll down